# iptables не как шлюз но для перенаправления?

Tags: iptables

Может ли iptables отрабатывать не как шлюз между двумя сетями, а как компьютер который будет получать на 1-й (допустим) интерфейс пакет на определенный порт не из своей подсети, менять в пакете его порт и ip назначения, маскировать (нат) обратный адрес, и отправлять пакет по новому адресу, и так выходит, что через тот же интерфейс.

UPD: ARM обращается к портам X и Y сервера1. Зеленое направление работает. Красное нет. принимать пакеты в iptables разрешено и на portX и на portY.
То что закоментарил - пробовал, не помогло. Сам Сервер1 нормально видит порт X Сервера3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по какому новому адресу отправлять пакет, если вы делаете только nat обратного ? И что значит "не из своей подсети", как пакет вообще попадет на машину, если он в другой подсети. Вернее кто его отправит на mac-адрес вашей машины, если отправитель видимо о вас не знает

Comment: по задумке АРМ пытается установить соединение с сервером на котором иптаблес, соответственно пакет придет на сервер с адресом назначения -этот сервер и портом Х. В задумке этот сервер должен полученный на порт Х пакет отправить на другой адрес и другой порт, замаскировав адрес отправителя. Ну и назад потом чтобы пакеты шли. Грубо говоря есть сеть в которой серверу (он не шлюз, ему просто открыли доступ) разрешен выход в другую сеть. в той другой сети второй сервак. надо АРМ из первой сети попытаться соединить с серваком во второй. Можно ли использовать для этого сервак первой сети с iptables

Comment: Вроде особых проблем не видно, на PREROUTING делаете REDIRECT или DNAT, на POSTROUNIG (эти пакеты уже с другим адресом назначения !) делаете SNAT. А то что пакет уйдет через ту же сетевуху вообще значения не имеет. Главное что бы ip_forward был включен

Comment: 1. вопрос, требующий бинарного ответа (да/нет) — плохой вопрос для данного сайта. 2. видимо, у автора вопроса что-то не получается, но подробностей, которые могли бы составить суть **хорошего** вопроса, не приведено (это можно сделать, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса). 3. так что в текущем состоянии вопрос подлежит закрытию.

Comment: на бинарный вопрос, кстати, ответ: да. ведь и в вопросе, и в комментарии от автора описана работа самого наибанальнейшего шлюза (маршрутизатора). несмотря на то, что автор вопроса, кажется, думает иначе.